# Expanding D3 Pie Chart to fill SVG

Tags: d3.js, ember.js

I am trying to achieve two things:

- Make the existing pie chart in my application fill the available SVG
  element it is rendered in.
- Make the SVG element fill the size of the containing div it sits in
  so it is responsive.

In my bar charts I achieve this by setting ScaleLinear and ScaleBand ranges on the X and Y scale but this doesn't seem to be an option within the pie charts (and then setting the SVG element to a height and width of 100%).

Code:

```
export default Component.extend({

  tagName: 'svg',

   attributeBindings: ['width, height'],
   classNameBindings: ['baseClass'],

   a: null,
   baseClass: 'pie-chart',
   color: null,
   data: null,
   labelArc: null,
   height: 400,
   radius: null,
   svg: null,
   width: 400,
   donutwidth: 75,

setSvg() {
     const {
       height,
       baseClass,
       width,
     } = this.getProperties(
       'height',
       'baseClass',
       'width'
     );
     const svg = select(`.${baseClass}`)
       .attr('width', width)
       .attr('height', height)
       .append('g')

       .attr('transform', `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`);

     this.set('svg', svg);
   },

   _setG(svg, p) {
     return svg.selectAll('arc')
       .data(p)
       .enter()
       .append('g')
       .attr('class', 'arc');
   },

   _setPie(data) {
     const p = pie().padAngle(0.02).value((d) => d.count)(data);

     return p;
   },

// Template
<svg width='100%' height='100%'></svg>
```

Any help is gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found i needed to set the initial margins to pad the SVG, then calculate max and min values for pie elements using the available svgWidth data

```
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 40};
  var svgWidth = window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth/4);
  var width = svgWidth,
      height = (Math.min(width) / 2) + 100,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;

  var oRadius = radius, //var holding value for the outer radius of the arc
      iRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 4, //var holding the value for the inner radius of the arc
      cRadius = 8; //var holding the value for the corner radius of the arc
  var piePad = 5;


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// Graphing Function
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function graph(_selection) {
       _selection.each(function(data) {

      var pie = d3.pie()
          .padAngle(.01)
          .sort(null)
          .value(function(d) { 
             // console.log(d.value.value)
            return d.value.value; 
          });  



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// Scales
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; }); 
    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
    var colorScale = setColorScale(max);


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// Pie Vars 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var pie = d3.pie()
        .padAngle(.01)
        .value(function(d) {return d.value;})
        // .value(function(d) { return d[1]; })
        .sort(null);

      var  arc = d3.arc()
        .padRadius(oRadius + piePad)
        .outerRadius(oRadius - piePad)
        // .innerRadius(radius - (radius/2.piePad));
        .innerRadius(iRadius);
        // .cornerRadius(cRadius);

      var outerArc = d3.arc()
        .padRadius(oRadius + piePad)
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);
        // .cornerRadius(cRadius);

      var arcOut = d3.arc()
        .padRadius(oRadius + piePad)
        .innerRadius(iRadius - piePad*4)
        .outerRadius(oRadius - piePad);
        // .cornerRadius(cRadius);

      var arcOver = d3.arc()
        .padRadius(oRadius + piePad)
        .innerRadius(iRadius - piePad*2)
        .outerRadius(oRadius - piePad*2);

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ////// Build Initial SVG
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      if (!svg){
        svg = d3.select(this).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "donut-group")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
      }

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ////// Add paths for pie
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var path = svg.selectAll("path").data(pie(data));

      path.enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class",animatePathIn)
         /// rest of path code
      } // end  graph
   return graph;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I haven't been able to get this to fire. When I add the margins and associated width/height values I get console errors to say that the width is undefined, even though console logging the value returns an integer. I have a twiddle here if you'd like to have a look: [link](https://ember-twiddle.com/f0451e839bf78f0fa5486f06caf56649?openFiles=templates.components.pie-chart.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.pie-chart.hbs)

Comment: your initially setting the dimensions as fixed numbers  ` let width = 500,
        height = 500,
        donutwidth =  75,` they need to be set on whats available, not what you pre define.

Comment: Apologies, that was for demonstrative purposes. I've realised why I was getting the errors I referred to earlier and it was my mistake not yours! The window.innerWidth is working from the entire browser window which is drawing me a huge SVG element that isn't linked to the parent div. I tried using parent.innerwidth instead which didn't change the result. I've updated the twiddle with current code [link](https://ember-twiddle.com/f0451e839bf78f0fa5486f06caf56649?openFiles=components.pie-chart.js%2Ctemplates.components.pie-chart.hbs)